# Is there an "orthogonal factorization" of bivariate functions that is analogous to the SVD of matrices?

Tags: functional-analysis, matrix-decomposition, svd

For a matrix $X \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$, we have the SVD decomposition
$$ X = U D V^\top, $$
where $U\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times r},\ V\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times r}$ are orthonormal matrices and $D=\text{diag}(\sigma_1,\dots,\sigma_r)$ is a diagonal matrix.

Now, let's consider the vector form
$ X = \sum_{k=1}^r \sigma_k u_k v_k^\top  $, where $u_k$, $v_k$ represent the $k$th column of $U$ and $V$, respectively. Then, the $(i,j)$th element of $X$ is
$$ x_{ij}  = \sum_{k=1}^r \sigma_k u_{ik} v_{jk}. $$
By regarding indexing as a mapping from integers to function values, I'm wondering if this continuous (functional) counterpart of SVD exists:
$$ x(s,t) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \sigma_k u_k(s) v_k(t), $$
such that $(u_k)$ and $(v_k)$ are orthonormal function series.

Does the factorization above exist? If yes, has anyone studied the approximation to the left side with a truncated series of the right side? If no, does any bivariate-to-univariate factorization exist?

Comment: May help: [Continuous analogues of matrix factorizations](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4277194/)

Comment: This is a good question and there is a ton of literature and applied work on this subject. Unfortunately, it also goes by many names depending on discipline. The big ones are Proper Orthogonal Decomposition (POD), Karhunen-Loeve Expansion (KL), or Empirical Orthogonal Functions (EOF). Here is one of the better brief expositions of this topic https://arxiv.org/pdf/1509.07526.pdf "POD for linear-quadratic Optimal Control" by Gubisch and Volkwein is also good.

Comment: @whpowell96, thx a lot for the references. I think the POD is just what I'm looking for.

Comment: I apologize for simply leaving a comment with some links, but I felt a good answer would be very very long

Comment: No worries, your clue has pointed me to rich related literature.